# update mysql table with a dataframe in python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I've a sample dataframe

```
city          sales
Newyork       6000 
Manhattan     5000
Ohio          4000
Buffalo       3000
```

I've a table in my db

```
id     city          sales 
1      Newyork        null
2      Buffalo        null
3      Manhattan      null
4      Ohio           null
5      Washington DC  null
```

Update query `update table set sales = {} where city = {}`

I've connected to my database with `sql-alchemy`

```
def connectToDatabase():
      db = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}'.format(MYSQL_USER,MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_HOST,MYSQL_DB))
      connection = db.connect()
      return connection
```

How can I update my table if sales is `>3000`

Result 'd be like

```
id     city        sales
1      Newyork      6000
2      Buffalo      null
3      Manhattan    5000
4      Ohio         4000
5      Washington DC null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (from https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp), your dataframe is a pandas dataframe with name df:

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  password="yourpassword",
  database="mydatabase"
)

for index, row in df.iterrows():   
    if row['sales'] > 3000:
        
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()

        sql = "INSERT INTO table(sales) VALUES (%s) WHERE city = " + str(row['city'])
        val = str(row['sales'])
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)

        mydb.commit()

        print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```